# Bing Location Control for Microsoft Bot Framework: Typing address in Facebook messenger does not work

Tags: c#, botframework

I am building bot with Microsoft Framework bot Sdk for C#. I have connected bot to Facebook Channel. I have implemented built in location dialog picker as FB Messenger's location picker GUI dialog as following:

```
var apiKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BingMapsApiKey"];
var prompt = "Where should I ship your order? Type or say an address.";
var locationDialog = new LocationDialog(apiKey, message.ChannelId, prompt, 
LocationOptions.UseNativeControl | LocationOptions.ReverseGeocode);
context.Call(locationDialog, (dialogContext, result) => {...});
```

(code from https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/blob/master/CSharp/README.md)

However, when I try to type in the address it re prompts the message "Tap on Send Location to proceed; type or say cancel to exit."
**Facebook dialog picture**
[image]

I do not understand why it does not allow me to type in the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use location from Facebook Messenger [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies?ncid=txtlnkusaolp00000618) to get this done.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for you post! However, does it only allow the user to send their location? Are there any options for them to be able to type the address? The Bing location control for Microsoft bot framework works quite well with Skype and web, that is users can type directly their address and location dialog processes it, however having a bit of an issue getting Facebook location to work.

Comment: Yes. I know that. I had similar issues. I found better solution in Facebook Messenger docs. 
It's the simplest solution to get location.

Please mark this as an answer :)