# Microsoft Builder SDK 3.8.1.0: Location dialog throws exception Method not found "Void Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.PromptDialog.Confirm"

Tags: c#, botframework

I am building bot with Microsoft Bot Framework and currently testing in Bot Framework channel emulator. 
I have updated Microsoft Bot builder SDK to version 3.8.1.0 as well as Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Location version 2.0.0. I have configured location dialog as following:
[image]

code from: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/tree/master/CSharp

However, after call to dialog it throws the following exception: 
[image]

Before the updated no exception was thrown and it worked well. I am just wondering if anyone else was experiencing same issue and was able to find solution? Thank you ;)

(code from: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/tree/master/CSharp)

Comment: More info can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/issues/107

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036803/bing-location-control-for-microsoft-bot-framework-typing-address-in-facebook-me/44040694#44040694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known issue the team is going to fix soon. It was reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/issues/107) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/issues/108). To unblock yourself you can just re-compile the library using the latest version of BotBuilder, that will make the trick.

#### Update

A new NuGet with the fix was released on May-24.Check https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Location?NormalizedVersion=2.1.0

Comment: hey, thank you very much for your response. I have followed the following steps  1. Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.Bot.Builder (to version 3.8.1)    2. Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Locatiom (to version 2.0.0) 3. Rebuild solution straight after. However, it still throws exception. Would you please be able to advise if I am on the right path?

Comment: Mmmm I don't think so. You need to rebuild Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Location using the new version of Microsoft.Bot.Builder and use the resulting dll in your app. Anyways, it seems that soon it will be a new release of Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Location since [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/pull/109) was merged

Answer (score 0):

New version of Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Location https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Location?NormalizedVersion=2.1.0